# How do you verify that a scheduled task exists on a server using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

also how can you tell if it is running, enabled/disabled, etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [Task Scheduler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(VS.85).aspx) that you can use to access information about tasks. (It is a com library, but you can call it from C# using pinvokes)

There is an [article on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx) that provides a .net wrapper for the API.

[There is also the [schtasks](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx) command - [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357(VS.85).aspx)]

Comment: checked out that codeProject wrapper. It works great.  I'm really surprised that there are no scheduleTask objects in the .net framework!

Answer (score 5):

The API can be installed [via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler). The package name is 'TaskScheduler'. (https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler)

The following example shows how you can test whether a task is installed using its name and if not install it with an hourly execution.

```
using (TaskService service = new TaskService())
{
    if (!service.RootFolder.AllTasks.Any(t => t.Name == "YourScheduledTaskName"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("YourScheduledTaskName is not installed on this system. Do you want to install it now? (y/n)");
        var answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer == "y")
        {
            var task = service.NewTask();
            task.RegistrationInfo.Description = "YourScheduledTaskDescription";
            task.RegistrationInfo.Author = "YourAuthorName";

            var hourlyTrigger = new DailyTrigger { StartBoundary = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 1, 0 , 0) };
            hourlyTrigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            task.Triggers.Add(hourlyTrigger);

            var taskExecutablePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "YourScheduledTaskName.exe");
            task.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(taskExecutablePath));

            service.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("YourScheduledTaskName", task);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

btw, IRT my accepted solution, here is the CodeProject wrapper code (see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx ) needed to verify that a scheduledTask exists

I use this in an Integration test so the Assert is NUnit..

```
public static void VerifyTask(string server, string scheduledTaskToFind)
{
     ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(server);

     string[] taskNames = st.GetTaskNames();
     List<string> jobs = new List<string>(taskNames);

     Assert.IsTrue(jobs.Contains(scheduledTaskToFind), "unable to find " + scheduledTaskToFind);

     st.Dispose();
}
```

to check if it is enabled, you can do the following:

```
Task task = st.OpenTask(scheduledTaskToFind);
Assert.IsTrue(task.Status != TaskStatus.Disabled);
```